# why is focusout event being fired multiple times?

Tags: jquery

I add a few `input` elements dynamically then attach a `focusout` event. When I run the code what happens is I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch to the next `input` element, then the `alert` box appears indefinitely one after another.

I thought I should get a single alert box when I switch from one input field to another. Then again after I leave that field I should get another alert. Instead of the expected behavior, as soon as I switch from one input field to another, I get alert boxes indefinitely freezing up the browser. I appreciate any help into understanding why is `focusout` event being fired indefinitely. Thanks!

```
//adding few input elements dynamically
$('#worker_payment_' + id).html('<input style="width: 54px;" type="text" value="' + w_payment + '">');
$('#worker_mileage_' + id).html('<input style="width: 54px;" type="text" value="' + w_mileage + '">');
$('#worker_reimburse_' + id).html('<input style="width: 54px;" type="text" value="' + w_reimburse + '">');
$('#worker_note_' + id).html('<input style="width: 54px;" type="text" value="' + w_note + '">');

$('#worker_action_' + id).html('<span style="font-size: 14px;"><g:submitButton name="Delete" class="button" onClick="handleDelete( current_selection ); return false;"/></span>');

$("#worker_name_" + id + " select").focus();

//now adding focusout events to each of these elements
$("#worker_name_" + id + " select").focusout(function() {
    alert("focus lost");
});

$('#worker_payment_' + id + ' input').focusout(function() {
    alert("focus lost");
});

$('#worker_mileage_' + id+ ' input').focusout(function() {
    alert("focus lost");
});

$('#worker_reimburse_' + id+ ' input').focusout(function() {
    alert("focus lost");
});

$('#worker_note_' + id+ ' input').focusout(function() {
    alert("focus lost");
});
```

Comment: `alert()` is taking focus away from the `input`, hence the event fires again,  and so on. This is another reason you should always use `console.log` when debugging.

Comment: use console.log("Focus Lost") instead of alert("Focus Lost") and watch the console to see the results.

Comment: `alert` and its cousins `prompt` and `confirm` have a complex and unhelpful interplay with focus. Don't use them in relation to focus events, the results vary from browser to browser and basically aren't pretty in any of them. See the link question's answers for details.

Comment: thanks a lot! that helped